# Which of the following is defined for all real numbers? (trig functions)

Tags: trigonometry

Today I had a test with a multiple choice question, that was:

Which of the following is defined for all real numbers?

a. $f(x) = \arcsin(x)$

b. $f(x) = \arccos(x)$

c. $f(x) = \arctan(x)$

d. $f(x) = \operatorname{arcsec}(x)$

e. none of the above

I chose none of the above. I almost chose arctan, tho I thought because arctan has to be between $- π/2 < Θ < π/2$, that would be wrong. I know sine is defined thru the same interval, and cos as between $0$ and $π$. But online, I'm seeing arctan as defined for all real numbers.

Comment: The *values* of $\arctan$ are in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, but it is defined over all real numbers.

Answer (score 7):

The question is about the domain of the function, not its range.  Since
$$\arctan x: (-\infty, \infty) \to \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
it is defined on the set of all real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the domain of a function, which the question was asking about, with the range of the function, which is not the same.

The domain of a function $f(x)$ is the set of values of $x$ for which the function is defined.  So for example, working with only real numbers, the domain of $f(x) = x^2$ is then all real numbers, since you can square any real number.  The range of $f(x) = x^2$ however is all non-negative real numbers.  So if I asked "is $f(x) = x^2$ defined for all real numbers," the answer would be yes; but if I asked "does $f(x) = x^2$ take on all real numbers as values of $f(x)$ the answer would be no.

Similarly, can you find the arctan of any real number $X$?  Sure you can:  draw a right triangle with legs $X$ and $1$, and measure the angle made, taking the negative sign if $x$ is negative.

Answer (score 1):

Since $-1 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1$.
arcsin$(x)$ is only defined between $-1 \leq x \leq 1$

(Similarly for arccos(x))

arcsec is *not* defined between $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, so it is not defined between the real numbers.

Now take arctan(x). Clearly tan(x) can take values of all the real numbers, and as such you can plug all these real numbers back into arctan(x), which makes the domain defined on all real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Aectan is defined for all $ -\infty < x < +\infty $. Being multiple valued is besides the point.